# Want to select a single column from a table in database and store it in a list asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, linq

i am working in asp.net and using entity framework 
I want to perform a query like so,

```
SELECT Name FROM Employees
```

i want to perform this query in asp.net using linq ?

Comment: Almost any tutorial will start with how to select data as one of the first examples. Start there, google tutorials or videos and start reading/watching. [so] is not the place to ask for guidance or tutorials or learn how to..., that is considered [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = (from c in context.Employees select c.Name).ToList();
```

OR

```
List<string> result = (from c in context.Employees select c.Name).ToList();
```